# Java send https request to a server

Tags: java, https, certificate, keystore, truststore

I have a java application dat sends https request to my server. I had to create a keystore with:

```
keytool -import -file mycert.cer -alias myalias -keystore keystore.jks
```

and use that as truststore in my java app. But the certificate on my server is valid for one year. After one year the certificate changes.

So does it mean I have to generate a new keystore when that happens? Or are there better ways of achieving this?

Comment: Get/buy a server certificate from a CA: [Where could I buy a valid SSL certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8404907/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, normally you have to upload the new certificate in your keystore whenever the certificate changes.

The purpose of certificate is to establish a trusted connection. The certificate tells your program that the URL it is trying to reach is actually the real URL and not a fake one.

Security always comes at a cost. Changing a certificate yearly is a minor overhead to the security it provides to avoid any DNS spoofing attacks.

To answer if there are better ways to do it - Yes, the better way is to import the certificate in the same keystore. You will not need to change the keystore.

You can use below command to achieve the same:

```
keytool -import -file newcert.cer -alias mynewcertificate -keystore keystore.jks
```

Enter password of your keystore when asked for.

Comment: Thank you but I don't see any difference between the command you gave and the one I used. Did you mean I can just use the old keystore and just import the new certificate instead of deleting the previous one and making a new one?

Comment: That's right. The command you have used and I have given are both same i.e. for adding a certificate to the keystore. Please note that these commands are importing the certificate, not creating the keystore as you mentioned.  You will have to repeat the same process with new certificate file after an year.

Answer (score 0):

Not.  You can simply add the new certificate to the keystore.  Once you are sure that the old one is no more used, you can delete it from the keystore.